# Python Seg Fault that makes no sense to me

Tags: python

I have read all over stack overflow and google about seg faults regarding python and my situation hasnt fell into anything I have read so far.

Basically I have wrote an API that accept HTTP from outside clients. The client POSTs a binary file to the API which I am going to be running some processes on and storing after.

I am importing a module which is coded in Python to do the actual data processing.

I am SSHed into the machine with the API and was able to execute the processes just fine through the command line interpreter. However when I try to execute the process in my API i get a segmentation Fault. The weird part to me was the exact same portion of the code literally copy and pasted in the command line interpreter worked fine. The Seg fault occurs right where a function from the imported module is called.

---------------------This is the Terminal interpreter-----------------------------------

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> postdata = open('binfile').read()
>>> postdata[0:10]
'MZ\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00'
>>> import atklite
>>> metadata = atklite.FileAnalysis(data=postdata).return_analysis()
>>> metadata
{'sha1': '1f0c33a18a417bb09f85add08b2a675c1deda5ca', 'analyzetime': 'Thu Jun 21 12:03:23 2012', 'ftype': 'PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows', 'ttime': 1340294603.405788, 'sha256': '287744fc9d7b4f509fc271cce0af873c2d53fd1aa678d96dfc9afa8d6d1ad7a0', 'ssdeep': '768:HA/gyc4PWUSrxWoG+RUlyesIkJAkV+xQHz3ClxEEAdK88uDC4wOVdfxCO/ysRXA9:g/gyc4PWUSrxWoG+RUlyesIkJAkV+xQc', 'md5': '000038fe4b46c210c37bdde767835007', 'size': 28672}
```

--------------This is the part of the API where it crashes------------------------

```
def POST(self):
                a = web.ctx.env.get("HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN", None)
                creds = authenticator(a)
                x = web.input()
                b = x.values()
                written = open('binfile', 'wb')
                for char in b[0]:
                        written.write(char)
                written.close()
                postdata = open('binfile').read()
                print postdata[0:10]
                analysis = atklite.FileAnalysis(data=postdata)  #SEG FAULTS HERE!!!!
                metadata = analysis.return_analysis()
```

---------------------------Imported Module function----------------------------------

```
class FileAnalysis:
  results = {'analyzetime': time.ctime(),'ttime': time.time()}
  hash_libs = ('md5','sha1','sha256')
  if ERROR:
    sys.exit('This function requires dependencies that aren\'t satisfied')
  __ssd = ssdeep()
  __ms = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_NONE)
  __ms.load()
  def __init__(self, data=None, filename=None):
    if filename:
        return(self.analyze_file(filename))
    if data:
        return(self.analyze_data(data))
  def hash_data(self, data):
    for lib in self.hash_libs:
        hl = getattr(hashlib, lib)
        self.results[lib] = hl(data).hexdigest()
  def hash_file(self, filename):
    hlibs = {}
    size = 0
    for lib in self.hash_libs:
        hlibs[lib] = getattr(hashlib, lib)()
    for chunk in read_chunks(open(filename, 'rb')):
        # We do this here so we don't have to read twice
        size += len(chunk)
        for hl in hlibs:
            hlibs[hl].update(chunk)
    self.results['size'] = size
    for hl in hlibs:
        self.results[hl] = hlibs[hl].hexdigest()
  def analyze_data(self, data):
    if not data:
        return False
    self.hash_data(data)
    self.results['size'] = len(data)
    self.results['ftype'] = self.__ms.buffer(data)
    self.results['ssdeep'] = self.__ssd.hash_bytes(data)
  def analyze_file(self, filename):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise IOError("File: %s doesn't exist" % filename)
    # Size is done inside the hash bytes function so we don't have to read multiple times
    self.hash_file(filename)
    self.results['ftype'] = self.__ms.file(filename)
    self.results['ssdeep'] = self.__ssd.hash_file(filename)
  def return_analysis(self):
    return (self.results)
  def dump(self):
    res = []
    for result in self.results:
        res.append("%s: %s" % (result, self.results[result]))
    return("\n".join(res))
```

Using Duncans advice a traced it to this

```
> /home/spezzino/ProcessingCode/atklite.py(93)analyze_data()
-> self.results['ftype'] = self.__ms.buffer(data)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magic.py(126)buffer()
-> def buffer(self, buf):
(Pdb) s
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magic.py(132)buffer()
-> return _buffer(self._magic_t, buf, len(buf))
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magic.py(132)buffer()->'PE32 executa...or MS Windows'
-> return _buffer(self._magic_t, buf, len(buf))
(Pdb) s
> /home/spezzino/ProcessingCode/atklite.py(94)analyze_data()
-> self.results['ssdeep'] = self.__ssd.hash_bytes(data)
(Pdb) s
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Can you post the output from the segfault?

Comment: im using Python    2.7.3

Comment: For clarity purposes, please could you edit post to indent def's inside the class?

Comment: There is really no output it just says Segmentation Fault once it gets to that line of code

Comment: At a rough guess it is dying either in the call to `self.__ms.buffer(data)` or `self.__ssd.hash_bytes(data)`. Try setting a breakpoint just before the call to `FileAnalysis` and stepping through the code until you find which line is actually dying. (Set a breakpoint with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` on the line before then single step with the `s` command or `n` to step across rather than through calls such as `self.hash_data(data)`).

Comment: I added the pbd trace to the body of the post

Comment: if you write as binary, should you not read as binary?

Comment: May be not relevant, but perhaps your file is being opened wrongly? I notice that you write the file with 'wb' but don't provide a read-mode. The default mode is 'r', not 'rb', so how about explicitly specifying a read-mode?

Comment: @AndrewCox great minds think alike :)

Comment: tried switching the read, it caused an error before the seg fault. The thing is is that from the terminal the code runs just as it should so i am sure the syntax is all correct

Comment: Done: defs indented, @JonClements

Comment: you could enable [faulthandler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler/) to get traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't have an explanation, but searching around it seems that there's an alternative wrapper for ssdeep, called [pydeep](https://github.com/kbandla/pydeep) that may be more reliable (it seems that the package you are using segfaults often on osx - maybe this will also work better with linux).

it provides pretty much the same interface (see link above) so should be easy to swap to.

Comment: The ssdeep lib was unstable. I ended up using pydeep and it worked.